# Function not running with QtConcurrent::run() when using QFutureWatcher

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

I want to call a function to delete files and folders from the system in a parallel thread called by `QtConcurrent::run()` (Qt for Embedded Linux 4.8). Using only a `QFuture<bool>` with `QFuture::waitForFinished()` to grab the result (I need to run some code right after the operation), I was able to make the system work.

But I want to display the ongoing result of the operation in a `QProgressBar` derived class with its `setValue(int)` called via signals and slots mechanism from inside the delete function, and what I get with the above method is a freezed main thread while the operation isn't finished, and that is inadmissible.

So I though about using `QFutureWatcher<bool>` and connecting it's `finished()` signal to another slot containing the remaining code to be run after the delete operation is finished.

The problem I'm facing is that, when I do this, the delete function is simply not run by `QtConcurrent::run()`! I checked that with printed messages to Terminal. Everything that occurs is that the `QFutureWatcher` calls its `finished()` signal without any execution of the delete files function (and that also happens if I use `QFutureWatcher::waitForFinished()`).

Is this some bug from Qt?

Regarding code, it's pretty exactly as in Qt Assistant: create the QFuture and QFutureWatcher globally, connect the finished() signal with the slot, call `QtConcurrent::run()`, and `setFuture()` to the future. Nothing special.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT

Following the request of Kuba, here is the relevant part of the code:

```
//Declared globally in the .cpp
QFuture<bool> future;
QFutureWatcher<bool> watcher;

//
void SelectRecordToDeleteWidget::slotDeleteRecordStateMachine()
{
    switch (deleteRecordStateMachine)
    {
        case PrepareToDelete:
        {
            //...
            connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(slotDeleteRecordStateMachine()),Qt::UniqueConnection);
            //...
        }
            break;

        case DeleteRecords:
        {
            //...
            future = QtConcurrent::run(removeFiles, QString(DEFAULT_RECORD_DIR) + "/" + recordList.at(aaa).second.second, poProgressDialog, &itemCounter);

            watcher.setFuture(future);

            qApp->processEvents();
            //...
        }
            break;

        case FinishDelete:
        {
            //Run code after deleting files
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This is all the code using QFuture and QFutureWatcher. The `removeFiles` is as follows (not forgetting that it works well without QFutureWatcher):

```
bool removeFiles(const QString dirName, Interface::ProgressDialog* const poProgressDialog, qint32* const itemDeletedCounter)
{
    bool result = true;

    try
    {
        QDir dir(dirName);

        if (dir.exists())
        {
            Q_FOREACH (QFileInfo info, dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::System | QDir::Hidden | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst))
            {
    //            if (Q_UNLIKELY(poProgressDialog->wasCanceled()))
    //                break;

                if (info.isDir())
                {
                    result = removeFiles(info.absoluteFilePath(),poProgressDialog,itemDeletedCounter);

                    if (!result)
                        return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = QFile::remove(info.absoluteFilePath());

                    if (!result)
                        return result;

                    if (!QMetaObject::invokeMethod(poProgressDialog, "setValue",
                                              Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                                              Q_ARG(qint32, *itemDeletedCounter)))
                    {
                        mDebugS(QString("removeFiles: %1QMetaObject::invokeMethod(poProgressDialog, \"setValue\"... failed!"));
                    }

                    ++(*itemDeletedCounter);

//                    mDebugS(QString("removeFiles: %1").arg(*itemDeletedCounter));
                }
            }

            result = dir.rmdir(dirName);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        const QString strTemp = QString("An error in a call to removeFiles");

        mDebugS(strTemp);
        mLog(strTemp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `waitForXxx` in any code. It blocks the event loop, uses a page worth of stack (!!), and leads to horrible pseudo-synchronous code style. It's as simple as that. When you want to do something when the operation finishes, do it in a slot or a functor attached to the `finished` signal.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without a code example. Nobody will recreate the code for you from a textual description. It's your job to post the question with the code included. *Nothing special* Are you serious? You've **just admitted** that it doesn't work. I can do it, and it works. I can't divine what you did wrong, sorry.

Comment: @KubaOber well I always avoid `waitForFinished()`; actually I just did it as part of trying to understand what was going on since I wanted to use `QFutureWatcher`'s signals from the beginning. Regarding code, I edited my question.